# Subclass vs container

Tags: scala

[Actor](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/concurrent/src/main/scala/scalaz/concurrent/Actor.scala) class defines `Node` as:

```
class Node[A](val a: A) extends AtomicReference[Node[A]]
```

Is it considered a good practice to create a linked list like this? What is the advantage over

```
class Node[A](val a: A, val prev: AtomicReference[Node[A]])
```

The former is certainly shorter, but IMO less readable as it mixes two entities.

Answer (score 2):

The usage patterns are more concise.  By extending `AtomicReference`, scalaz can use atomic calls on each Node directly.

An example method from Actor.scala:

```
def !(a: A): Unit = {
    val n = new Node(a)
    val h = head.getAndSet(n)
    if (h ne null) h.lazySet(n)
    else schedule(n)
}
```

The same code, with your variation:

```
def !(a: A): Unit = {
    val n = new Node(a, new AtomicReference[Node[A]])
    val h = head.prev.getAndSet(n)
    if (h ne null) h.prev.lazySet(n)
    else schedule(n)
}
```